# What is the difference between thread states and process states?

Tags: multithreading, process, lifecycle

What I learned is if a process got blocked, it will be swapped out to the disk and wait for wake-up event. But, if a process can have multiple threads, what if a thread is blocked? For example, one of the threads waits for a keyboard eveny, the thread will be blocked. Then will the process also be blocked, or is it possible that only the thread is blocked and process is running?

Comment: Re, "if a process got blocked, it will be swapped out to the disk" You have been reading some very old books. Swapping whole processes was state-of-the-art memory management back in the 1960s, but starting in the 1970s, it was replaced by _[paging](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Paging)_.  In any modern OS, the memory image of a blocked process will be copied out to secondary storage (e.g., disk) in relatively small increments called _pages_, and and that will only happen if it the RAM that those pages occupy is needed by some other process...

Comment: ...also, Paging is pretty much de-coupled from the process state. RAM Pages typically are selected for re-use based on how long since the process last accessed the page, and without regard for whether the process is running, or waiting to run, or waiting for I/O, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What I learned is if a process got blocked, it will be swapped out to the disk and wait for wake-up event.

You're probably reading some very old documentation. Likely by "process" it means something scheduled by the kernel.

> But, if a process can have multiple threads, what if a thread is blocked? For example, one of the threads waits for a keyboard event, the thread will be blocked. Then will the process also be blocked, or is it possible that only the thread is blocked and process is running?

If you define a "process" as a container that consists of an address space, file descriptor set and so on and that can contain more than one thread, then there is no such thing as a process being blocked. What would block a process exactly?